# Осваиваю Си, не могу понять почему в одном случаи все печатает отлично, в другом белиберду

Tags: c

Должен напечатать массив, там где закомментировал через printf все работает отлично, а там где в оригинале (без комментов) печатает белиберду. Не понимаю, почему в одном случаи все ок, а в другом откуда он непонятные цифры берет?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>                 
#include <stdlib.h>                 



void    ft_putchar(char c)          /* функция печати символа */
{
write(1, &c, 1);
}


void    ft_putnbr(int nb)           /* Функция вывода числа */
{
int temp;                       
int size;                       /* создадим переменню для хранения размера числа*/

size = 1;                       /* Установим ей начальный размер */

if (nb < 0)                     /* Проверяем яляется полученное нами число в nb отрицательным если число отрицательное то в начале выведем этот '-' символ. */  
{                               /* а содержимое переменной nb делаем положительным с помощью хитрости( nb = -nb) помня из математики что минус на минус дает плюс */
    ft_putchar('-');
    nb = -nb;                   
}
if (nb == -2147483648)
    {   
        ft_putchar('2');
        nb = 147483648;
    }
temp = nb;                      /* Сохраним в переменную temp наше число nb для вычисления размера этого числа */

while ((temp /= 10) > 0)        /* Вычисляем размер числа c помощью накопления количества умноженых десяток друг на друга*/ 
size *= 10;                 /* Если результ деления нашего числа в temp на 10 больше нуля то увеличиваем переменную size умножив ее содержимое на 10 */

/* НУЖО ПОМНИТЬ что при делении целого числа на целое результат сохраняемый в переменной типа int будет без плавающей точки. 
** она автоматически отбрасывается */ /* ПРимер: делим 4  на 10  в итоге результат будет 0.4 а вот сохраниться в переменной 
** типа int только 0 по тому что все после точки отбрасывается и не записывается в целочисленную переменную. */

temp = nb;                      /* Восстановим расстерзаноеделением число в переменную temp оно нам снова понадобится 
** для того чтобы отделить цифры нужного нам числа и напечатать по отдельности */

while (size)                    /* Проверяем длинну числа если длинна еще не равна нулю (в результате уменьшения на 10 в цикле) то продолжаем работу цикла */
{
    ft_putchar((char)((temp / size)) + 48); /* Делим число на размер, который у нас получился */   /* тут тоже хитрость */  
    /* Допустим размер полученогонами числа 345 получисля равным 100 */ 
    /* Деля 345 на 100  мы получим 3.45*/ /* 0.45 отбрасывается по тому что идет приведение к целому числу */ /* и остаеться 3 */
    /* Так вот мы и отделяем 3 от 45 и уже можем ее напечатать тройку прибавив к ней 48, чтоб полуить код символа '3' */
    
    temp %= size;               /* Здесь с помощь деления числа temp (в примере у нас это 345) по модулю на size (в примере у нас это 100) мы получим 
    ** оставшуюся часть без первого символа temp ( т.е у нас получится 45. Тройка канула в лету. Так мы ее отбрасываем чтоб потом,
    ** на новой итерации цикла напечатать 4 и 5 и т.д по мере отделения и печати чисел,  и помере того как size уменьшается */
    
    size /= 10;                 /* После то как отделили 3 от 45 в числе 345 и после того как оставили себе только 45 для дальнейшего отделения. число 100 нам больше не нужно.
    ** Так что делим size на 10 чтобы в след итерации число 45 уже делилось на 10 отдавая 4 на печать, и еще 45 делилось по модулю на 10 сохраняя 5 
    ** на следующую итерацию, потом снова уменьшение size на 10 (чтобы можно было работать с temp, которое теперь уже хранит 5). 
    ** Теперь 5 делм на 1 получаем пять отдаем его на печать, 5 деленное по модулю на 1 сохраняет в переменную 0 но это нам уже не нужно.
    ** Потомучто дальше size делится на 10 снова и размер size становится равным нулю. А при след итерации цикл будет проверять размер size 
    ** и если он равен 0 то цикл завершается */
    /* И жили они долго и счастливо, конец */
}
}



void    ft_putnbarr(int *num, int l)/* Функция для печати массива целых чисел */
{
while(l-- > 0)
    {
        ft_putnbr(*num++);
        ft_putchar(' ');
    }
}


int ft_ultimate_range(int **range, int min, int max)
{
int *p_int;

if (min >= max)                 /* Проверяем соответствуют ли числа условиям */
return 0;

p_int=malloc(sizeof(int)*(max-min));

if (p_int==NULL)
    return 0;

int i=0;
while (min+i<max) {
    p_int[i]=min+i;
    i++;
}

*range=p_int;

return i;
}


int main(void) 
{
int *arr;

ft_putnbarr(arr, ft_ultimate_range(&arr, 5,10));

 // ft_ultimate_range(&arr, 5,10);
 // 
 // int i=0;
//  while (arr[i]!='\0') {
//      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
//      i++;
 // }

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Второй вариант тоже не должен работать.  У вас цикл до нуля `while (arr[i]!='\0')`, а в функции `ft_ultimate_range()` вы разве добавляете в конец массива ноль?

Comment: Логично, но почему тогда у меня работает? Хм...

Comment: Это называется UB - undefined behavior - неопределенное поведение. Может работать, а может рухнуть. У вас там выход за пределы массива. Видимо повезло что следующий после массива элемент в памяти оказался нулем и не было пересечения сегмента памяти. Поэтому отработало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандарт не указывает в каком порядке вычислять аргументы.

Первый аргумент в `ft_putnbarr(arr, ft_ultimate_range(&arr, 5,10));` передаётся мусорным значением указателя. Чтобы функция `ft_ultimate_range` выполнялась **первой**, нужно писать отдельно.

```
int x =ft_ultimate_range(&arr, 5,10);
ft_putnbarr(arr,x);
```

---

Вторая проблема с приоритетами операций

```
ft_putnbr(*num++);
```

эта запись не очень читается, правильнее так :

```
ft_putnbr(*num);
++num;
```

Comment: 'int x =ft_ultimate_range(&arr, 5,10);
ft_putnbarr(arr,x);' - помогло, спасибо. Только вопрос, ведь до этого он во всех 5 числах мусор печатал, не совсем понимаю почему. Мне хотелось бы именно разобраться, а не тупо решить задачу.

Comment: И почему надо писать отдельно в этом случаи, ведь обычно функции в функциях пишут и нет проблем.

Comment: первому аргументу компилятор передаёт копию указателя со случайным значением. обычно записывает его в регистр процессора. второй аргумент вычисляется, используя вашу функцию. Эта функция исправляет переменную, записывая правильный указатель памяти. Но функция уже получила первый аргумент как указатель.То,что вторая функция изменило где-то память уже не имеет значения. Второй раз запускать вычисление первого аргумента никто не будет.

Comment: Блин ни фига не понял, ладно как нибудь потом разберусь. Спасибо за объяснение.